# Why does my IrfanView command not work on batch file but work when typing directly in CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, irfanview

I'm a first-day user of IrfanView and have a question. I have a bunch of multi-page tiff files and I want to split all of them individually. So I write a batch file with the command like this:

```
C:\Program Files\IrfanView>i_view64.exe D:\originaldirectory\filename1.tif /extract=(D:\newdirectory,tif)
C:\Program Files\IrfanView>i_view64.exe D:\originaldirectory\filename2.tif /extract=(D:\newdirectory,tif)
```

...and so on...

I put the batch file on D drive, let's say in folder "batchfolder". But it can't do the job, this message shows up for each unsuccessful case (all of them were unsuccessful):

```
D:\batchfolder>C:\Program Files\IrfanView D:\originaldirectory\filename1.tif /extract=(D:\newdirectory,tif) 1>i_view64.exe
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I guess that has something to do with the batch file location, so I bring it to C drive. But still it can't run properly, this time a different message shows up:

```
C:\>C:\Program Files\IrfanView D:\originaldirectory\filename1.tif /extract=(D:\newdirectory,tif) 1>i_view64.exe
Access is denied.
```

This `C:\>C:\` makes me think maybe the `C:\` part on the batch file was redundant. So I take it out to make it look like this:

```
Program Files\IrfanView>i_view64.exe D:\originaldirectory\filename1.tif /extract=(D:\newdirectory,tif)
```

...

But it doesn't work, either with the batch file on D or C drive.
I then try to type it directly in the CMD window and it works normally, like this:

```
C:\Program Files\IrfanView>i_view64.exe D:\originaldirectory\filename1.tif /extract=(D:\newdirectory,tif)
```

Can you tell where my batch file goes wrong?

This is another question. Typing (or copy and paste) the batch file contents into the CMD works OK. But upon successful splitting, the original, multi-image file automatically opens. How can I deactivate this feature?

Note: Cross-post here: `https://irfanview-forum.de/showthread.php?t=11150&p=47111#post47111`. Hope it doesn't violate policy.

Comment: `1>i_view64.exe` writes the output of the preceding command line into a file called `i_view64.exe`, overwriting it if it already exists; I assume you do not want that, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enclose paths/filenames with spaces into quotes to tell the interpreter, it's not two words, but one string (or even better: get used to always enclose path/filenames):

```
"C:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" "D:\originaldirectory\filename1.tif" /extract=("D:\newdirectory",tif)`
```

Before you build a batchfile with dozends or hundreds of nearly identical lines, use a `for` loop to process all `.tif` files in the folder:

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("D:\originaldirectory\*.tif") do (
  "C:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" "%%~fa" /extract=("D:\newdirectory",tif)
)
```

see `for /?` for more information.

Comment: Thanks much, that works fine and the loop is the hack. An issue with both solutions, though, is that the original tiff files open when being split, which I don't need. Is there a way that I tell the command just to split files quietly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the executable with quotes in the batch. Also, the `>` in the path will not work either. Also consider using a for loop instead of creating single batch lines.

Please try this:

```
"C:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64.exe" "D:\originaldirectory\filename1.tif" /extract=("D:\newdirectory",tif)
```